# VS2013 lost intellisense from css to less

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, intellisense

I am using VS2013 with Resharper 8.2 installed.

I've gone from using CSS to LESS using dotless to compile at runtime.

I've completely lost the editor intelligense - like clicking on a css class would take me to the css file.

Is there any way to restore this or make it work with LESS? VS2013 or Resharper don't mind which.